# How to change post published date to today date with SQL

Tags: sql, date

How to change already published post date and time to current date and time using SQL.

I have a solution for the year but I don't know how to change the whole date to the current date and time.

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date = post_date + INTERVAL 1 YEAR WHERE YEAR(post_date) = 2020;`